# Eigenvalues of graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Given an undirected, unweighted graph $G$, let $A_G$ denote the graph's adjacency matrix. 
I want to understand in what cases there exists negative eigenvalue for $A_G$, for example, any claim of the form "$G(n,p)$ has at most $x$ negative eigenvalues" would be great for me. 
If there is any special case where $A_G$ is positive definite, or any case where it is possible to bound the absolute value of the negative eigenvalues - that would be very helpful. 
In addition, does it possible to insert only self-loops in order to "fix" the graph so it won't have negative eigenvalues?

Comment: what is your definition of adjacency matrix?  In particular, what's your rule for deciding the values of its diagonal entries?  I ask this because you can uniformly shift your eigenvalues up or down by uniformly shifting the entries on the diagonal of your matrix up or down.

Comment: @user296055: If you consider small examples like the complete graphs on 1 or 2 or 3 vertices, what can you find yourself? In these simple cases you can calculate the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix by hand.

Comment: The trace of $A_G$ corresponds to the sum of its eigenvalues. Since $\rm{tr}{A_G} = 0$ it follows that any graph with at least one edge must have a negative eigenvalue